# How do I make a serial field auto increment and be a foreign key - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables and I am trying to create a `Foreign Key` between the two.  Here is the structure of my tables:

```
create table users (
    id serial, 
    user_name varchar(50)
);

create table playlists (
    id serial, 
    user_id integer references users(id)
);
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users"
```

Why is there not a `unique constraint`?  If I create the `id` in the `users` table as `integer PRIMARY KEY`, then everything works fine.  How do I fix this where the `users` id auto increments and can be the `FK` in the `playlists` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a column of type `serial` doesn't make it the primary key or constraint it in any way. `serial` just creates an `integer` column, creates a sequence, and attaches the sequence to the column to provide default values. From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

> In the current implementation, specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname SERIAL
> );
> ```
>
> is equivalent to specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
> );
> ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
> ```

If you want your `id serial` columns to be primary keys (which you almost certainly do), then say so:

```
create table users (
    id serial not null primary key, 
    user_name varchar(50)
);

create table playlists (
    id serial not null primary key, 
    user_id integer references users(id)
);
```

Comment: When I do that, then I have to manually specify an `id`.  How do I get it to auto increment? - NEVERMIND.  This was a permissions problem.